# How to reference a view inside an element from my ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

So I have created a custom adapter for my ListView with three Views - TextView, ImageView and a basic View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/AllNotesFragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/addNoteTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:fontFamily="@font/ukij_qolyazma"
    android:text="+new"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/deleteNoteImageButton"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:fontFamily="@font/ukij_qolyazma"
    />

<View
    android:id="@+id/underlineView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:background="@color/colorMainDark" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/notesListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">
</ListView>
```

I have created and instantiated the ListView

```
        notesListView = view.findViewById(R.id.notesListView);
```

And filled it with a bunch of my notes

```
        notes = (ArrayList<Note>) db.getAllNotesForDay(NotesForDayActivity.getRememberDay(),
            NotesForDayActivity.getRememberMonth(),
            NotesForDayActivity.getRememberYear());
    for (Note note : notes) {
        noteTitles.add(note.getTitle());
    }

        NotesListAdapter adapter = new NotesListAdapter(((NotesForDayActivity) getActivity()).getContext(), notes);
        notesListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

With my custom adapter:

```
public class NotesListAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {

private static final String TAG = "NotesListAdapter";
public static Context context;
private RelativeLayout notesListRelativeLayout;
private TextView noteTitleTextView;
private ImageView tickImage;
private View underlineView;

private List<Note> notes;
// !
private View listItemsView;

public NotesListAdapter(Context context, List<Note> notes) {
    this.notes = notes;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NotesForDayActivity.getCountNotes();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return notes.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    listItemsView = convertView;
    if (listItemsView == null) {
        listItemsView = LayoutInflater.from(NotesForDayActivity.context).inflate(R.layout.notes_list_layout, null);
    }

    underlineView = listItemsView.findViewById(R.id.underlineView);
    notesListRelativeLayout  = (RelativeLayout) listItemsView.findViewById(R.id.notesListRelativeLayout);
    noteTitleTextView = (TextView) listItemsView.findViewById(R.id.noteTitleTextView);
    tickImage = (ImageView) listItemsView.findViewById(R.id.tickImageView);
    noteTitleTextView.setText(notes.get(position).getTitle());

    return listItemsView;
}
```

I can access an item inside my ListView with a OnItemClickListener, but I do not know how to access a View inside that particular Item of my ListView.

So If I set my OnClick like this:

```
        notesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
    });
```

How can I reference one of the three Views in that item. For example I need to set the visibility of my imageview:

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, OnItemClickListener will return the view, so that you can get access through that view

```
notesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
             ImageView tickImage = view.findViewById(R.id. tickImageView);
             if(tickImage!=null){
                 tickImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              }
            }
        });
```